# How to get changes in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, observablecollection

```
public ObservableCollection<IndividualEntityCsidClidDetail> IncludedMembers { get; set; }
```

Let say I have a reference to `IncludedMembers` I want an event to occur when collection items are added/removed/edited.

Comment: Are you using the collection in a WPF or WinForms environment?  What are you trying to achieve?  Binding might be better than event handling if you are in WPF.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

handle the `CollectionChanged` event

//register the event so that every time when there is a change in collection `CollectionChangedMethod` method will be called

```
    yourCollection.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler 
(CollectionChangedMethod);
```

Create a method like this

```
private void CollectionChangedMethod(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
       //different kind of changes that may have occurred in collection
       if(e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            //your code
        }
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
        {
            //your code
        }
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            //your code
        }
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move)
        {
            //your code
        }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't with simply changes of the fieds of objects in includeMembers

Comment: to simplify changes in the members , use notify property changed in the members class

Comment: What about `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset`? Does it also call `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove`?

Answer (score 5):

Just register to the collection's [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event.  It will raise events when you add or remove items or otherwise, change the contents of the collection.

If you want to receive events when properties of the items in the collection change, you'd need to make sure that the items are [`IObservable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) first then [`Subscribe()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782981.aspx) to the individual objects.

Answer (score -4):

That is what observable collections are for.

Simply bind to the collection and you are sorted!

Comment: The OP asked how to listen to changes in the collection. He didn't discuss binding...